# RecyclerView: how to clear cached/recycled views?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use a RecyclerView to display a list of items with a list layout. I switch from a list layout to a grid layout, showing just a subset of all the data when in grid layout. This switch uses a different layout XML than when list layout is presented.

All this works well, except that when I scroll, recycled (cached?) list layout views populate the grid, mixed in with proper grid layout view items. In other words, instead of using my `layout_grid.xml` for each item's layout in the RecyclerView, I get items using the `layout_list.xml` layout, but in a grid format.

This tells me the LayoutManager is working correctly, switching from a list to grid layout. But not all item view items are recreated using the grid xml layout, but rather recycled list layout views are used.

I tried `RecyclerView.removeAllViews()`, `RecyclerView.removeAllViewInLayout()`, `RecyclerView.swapAdapter()` (to force adapter reload), all to no avail.

**Update:**

If I scroll two positions down in the list, and then switch from list to grid, the first two positions do not go through onCreateViewHolder(), but straight to onBindViewHolder() and are therefore not forced to use the grid layout xml. Instead those first two position items are recycled (I think) and displayed in their list layout format.

Comment: The Recycler is great to use, but it has all of these really odd, small tidbits that cause hours of frustration. I'm glad you asked this question, as it helped me tremendously. Upvoted your question, and the answer. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok now I understand. You use both layouts? There is a method to return the viewtype for a list/grid element (id/position). You have too implement this method correctly that the adapter can recycle the correct layout for the new view. 
Do you understand what I mean? :)

Comment: I have a getItemViewType(int position) implemented to determine if I have an empty view. Should I be poking around there to determine what viewtype I'm dealing with?

Comment: Yes exactly. Otherwise the recyclerview has no chance to know which viewtype to recycle

Comment: Ok, I see what you are getting at. But where do I set the view type? It seems to return 0 for either list or grid layout.

Comment: You have to return the viewtype manually based on the index and then you can read it in the create method/bindViewHolder method

Comment: Ahh... I see. Manual labor. :-) I'm going to give this a shot tonight (gotta run for now). Thanks for pointing this out to me. If successful, I'll mark the answer when done.

Comment: No problem. If you need further help with that let me know, then I can implement some basic stuff for your understanding

Comment: Why did you delete my answer @mraviator? I give you the hint, so please don't delete my answer and give it some reputation. Thanks.

Comment: I did not delete your comments @its-tomweber. I was surprised myself when they were gone this morning. I want i credit you. Let me see if it's possible now.

Comment: Ok that's weird but please mark it as an answer. You know about the reputation and it looks like I helped you ;) Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 29):

Use

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!! I was creating a phone number list, and testing adding/deleting items. If I added a new item, after deleting one, the item that I deleted would appear as the new item. I spent hours looking at my arraylist, and tried multiple methods of fixing the issue - until I figured the data was somehow cached.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like the accepted answer is the right one for your case, returning a different viewType is probably what you needed to do.

If anyone does need to find a way to clear cached view holders and ended up in this thread, here is what I found that worked.

You need to call `setLayoutManager(null)` and `setAdapter(null)`. If you want to keep your adapter, you can do something like `adapter = getAdapter(); setAdapter(null); setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: In my case, setting the `layoutmanager(null)` **and** `setAdapter(null)` worked for me in my case. This saved myself from pulling my hair out!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. The solution suggested by Mann works well. An other option would be to set the RecycledViewPool of the RecyclerView to a new instance. That works for me as well.

```
recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());
```

But I think overriding the getItemViewType() is the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 4):

They key here was to override `getItemViewType(int position)` and set it up so that I could check which view type (list or grid) I'm dealing with for that position and then set the appropriate view handling for that position in `onbindViewHolder()`. Below, `viewFormat` is simply an int that I set to either list or grid when the user taps the menu button to change the format.

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (listData.size() == 0) {
            return EMPTY_VIEW;
        } else if (viewFormat == Constants.LIST_FORMATTED) {
            return Constants.LIST_FORMATTED;
        } else if (viewFormat == Constants.GRID_CONDITION) {
            return Constants.GRID_CONDITION;
        }
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
```

A user who posted comments on my original post made me aware of this, but unfortunately those comments were edited out. I thank that user for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
final int targetCacheSize = 2;
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(targetCacheSize);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please add some explanation for your code and how it answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview has view caching as well as recycled views pool (view holders pool).

Cache is of views (views with populated data). When LayoutManager tells recyclerview that view is no longer visible and needed, recyclerview checks if that view is still valid for particular position, if it is valid then it is added to cache, so when next time LM asks for the view for that position it returns from cache as it is.

Then what is recycled views pool? When views are removed from cache or are no more valid views, then data related to those views is cleared and only view holder object is kept in pool. Depending on itemType, pool can have view holders of different item types.

Now, in your case, your views are not valid for that particular position as you want to show altogether different view. So, your adapter should tell recyclerview that all the views are invalid. Only way to do is by using notifyDataSetChanged for all items. Recyclerview will remove views from cache and add those to recyler views pool. So now, when LM asks for view, either recycled view(according to itemType) or newly created view will be returned, and adapter will bind data to these views.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this
Simple !!

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0,adapter.getItemCount());

  adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0,adapter.getItemCount());
                   for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                         ////
                        data_List.add(data);
                    }
```