# RecyclerView not deleted inside RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android

I have a recyclerview adapter that is based on inflating two different card layouts. This adapater is dynamically updated with new cards and therefore each of the cards in the adapter needs to be updated as well. For each of the cards, there are a progressbar showing random generated data.

However, the problem Im facing is when I remove one of the cards in my list, the reference for the deleted card is not removed (the onCreateViewHolder is not called and therefore does not update the views), instead the cards left are just writing over the layout of the "deleted" card. The text on the card is correct and it removes the correct item from the list, but the progress bar is still having the old reference for the old card, which makes it adding values that corresponds to the deleted card.

To illustrate the problem, I'm adding random data to each of the cards in the progressbar depending on the movement name. So regardless of the card, the movement card named "Open Hand" should always add random data between 0-20, "Close hand" 20-60" and "Pronation" 60-100".

Here is everything working as supposed after adding three cards:
[After inserted three cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwIp9.png)

But when I delete the two first cards "Open hand" and "Close hand", the "Pronation" card left is showing the data in progress bar that actually corresponds to the "Open hand" data range. So why isn't the referencing correct?
I've tried calling both onDataSetChange(); and notifyItemRemoved(pos); 
[After deleted two cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBWpy.png)

My adapter code:

```
public class ParameterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    List<Movement> movements;

    public ParameterAdapter() {
        this.movements=movementList;
    }

    class AddCard extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public AddCard(View inflate) {
            super(inflate);
        }
    }

    class Card extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView movement;
        TextView channel;
        TextView remove;
        ProgressBar strength;
        TextView graph;
        LinearLayout expandedView;
        LineChart lineChart;
        Movement mov;
        public Card(View itemView, Movement m) {
            super(itemView);
            movement = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movementText);
            channel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.channelNameText);
            remove = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.removeCard);
            strength = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBarStrength);
            graph = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.graphTextButton);
            expandedView = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailsNr2);
            lineChart = (LineChart) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linechartCard);
            mov=m;
            channel.setText(m.getChannel());
            //Setup real time graph
            setupLineChart(mov, lineChart, mov.getId());
            // Start adding random data to the graph
            startAddingRandomData();
        }

        public void startAddingRandomData() {
            new Thread(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            while (true) {
                                int generatedData;

                                // Depending on what type of movement, add slightly different generated random data
                                // (to be sure that the views are correctly updated when removed for instance)
                                if(mov.getSettingsType().equals(SettingsDbHelper.MOVEMENTS_STRING[0])){
                                    // Add random generated data between the span 0-20
                                    generatedData=generateRandomData(0,20);
                                } else if (mov.getSettingsType().equals(SettingsDbHelper.MOVEMENTS_STRING[1])) {
                                    // Add random generated data between the span 20-60
                                    generatedData=generateRandomData(20, 60);
                                } else {
                                    // Add random generated data between the span 60-100
                                    generatedData=generateRandomData(60, 100);
                                }
                                //Set the progress bar
                                strength.setProgress(generatedData);

                                // Add the random generated data to the graph
                                addEntry(mov, lineChart, generatedData);

                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(300);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();

        }
    }

    public int generateRandomData(int n1, int n2){
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextInt(n2 - n1) + n1;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View vSetting=null;
        View vCard=null;
        // If its the first position, then inflate the "add movement" card.
        if(viewType==0) {
           vSetting = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_parameter_cardview, parent, false);
           return new AddCard(vSetting);
       }else if(viewType>0) {
            // Otherwise, if it's not the first position, then inflate a "movement card" and create the corresponding movement item
            vCard = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_movement, parent, false);
            Movement m = movementList.get(viewType - 1);
            return new Card(vCard, m);
       }else {
         // For some reason, this occurs
         return null;
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,final int position) {
        // "Add movement" card
        if(position==0){
            ((AddCard)holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddMovement.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_MOVEMENT);
                }
            });

        // "Movement" item card
        } else if(position>0) {
            final boolean isExpanded = position == mExpandedPosition;
            ((Card) holder).expandedView.setVisibility(isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            ((Card) holder).graph.setActivated(isExpanded);
            ((Card) holder).graph.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1 : position;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            // Get the type of movement
            Movement m = movementList.get(position - 1);

            // This lets the real-time graph view be created before actual adding any data.
            m.setChartCreated(1);

            //Update the textviews inside the card
            ((Card)holder).movement.setText(m.getMovement());
            ((Card)holder).channel.setText(m.getChannel());
            ((Card)holder).remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Movement m = movementList.get(position - 1);
                    //Remove the item from the list
                    remove(m);
                    // Get ID and settings type in order to update the entry
                    String id=m.getId();
                    String settingsType = m.getSettingsType();
                    //Update the entry
                    settingsdb.updateSetting(settingsType,id,"false");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Remove item from the list
    public void remove(Movement data) {
        int position = movementList.indexOf(data);
        movementList.remove(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        // (+ 1 one to compensate for the first card)
        notifyItemRemoved(position + 1);

    }


    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //Return the position
     return position;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // (+1 to compensate for the first card)
        return movementList.size()+1;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think, you need to remove notifydataset hanged() method from remove() method

Comment: Thanks! It worked, however, it recreating the views with an annoying flash. I saw this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951473/recyclerview-how-to-clear-cached-recycled-views

So I tried this as well: RecyclerView.removeAllViews(), this also solves the problem, and without the annoying flash

Comment: For that you need to disable animation of itemRemoved of RecyclerView

Comment: I think notifyitemremoved(position) is best. Not position+1

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm now, used this one: ((SimpleItemAnimator) RecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

Comment: I faced same problem,  and i used this method